# Corda linear state uniqueness

Tags: corda

I'm using Corda 4.0. While using linear states I found out that it is possible to create multiple linear states with same linear id (external id and UUID).
As per my logic for non fungible digital assets, linear id suppose to be unique, something like unique token in blockchain implementations.

In database, in **vault_linear_states** (same as **vault_states** and **vault_fungible_states**) table, I can see that primary key constraint defined as "**output_index**, **transaction_id**"

If some state will be changed multiple times, there will be multiple entries for same linear.

**output_index** column as I see in DB always "0".

Question:

1) What is purpose of **output_index**? Didn't find appropriated information.

2) How to work properly with linear states in terms of uniqueness? Should I programmatically select and check before insert or there is some other ways to deal with that?

Answer (score 0):

*1) Output index is the index of the previous sub transaction as one transaction can have multiple sub transactions. The reason why its always 0, if there are more sub transactions then it will be 0,1,2 so on.*

*2) First create the linear state return its unique id after that use same id to query the vault and use it as the input state in the transaction builder and updated one as the output state creating chain.*

**more info can be found here https://docs.corda.net/key-concepts-transactions.html**